# Excel formula of Extract Unique items from list with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, extract

As the title says : How do we extract unique items with criteria using excel formula ? 
Here's my data example, i'd like to extract unique items of 'Nama' but only if s/he have more than 2 'Kd_Makul'.

[image]

Comment: only formulas are allowed

Answer (score 1):

> but only if s/he have more than 2 'Kd_Makul'

I am assuming this means unique `Nama` with more than 2 records.

Enter the following *array formula* in the `Cell G2` :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15, MATCH(0, (COUNTIF($G$1:G1, $B$2:$B$15)+(NOT(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$15,$B$2:$B$15)>2))), 0)),"")
```

Commit this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. See image for reference.

[image]