# Generate summary gantt chart from detailed activities

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, schedule, gantt-chart

I want to create a gantt chart summary that shows a person´s whole "busy" and "free" schedule by day and in a single row, from a detailed gantt chart with a list of activities of different people in multiple rows.

**Basically go from this:**

[image]

**To this:** (which I created Manually)

[image]

To be able to give a summary of people´s shifts free time between activities.

Right now I´m just using this formula to compare the start and end date in each row and produce a "1" if the condition is True, then I just condition formatted the whole Gantt cells.

`=IF(AND(Q$8>=$N12,DAY($K12)<>DAY($J12)),1,IF(AND(Q$8>=$N12-0.00001,Q$8<$O12-0.00001),1,""))`

[image]

I have no idea how to start. I was thinking of doing the nest things:

1. Create a table of the names of all the possible people to be added in the gantt chart.
2. Program the macro to create a new sheet with the same template.
3. Program a loop which starts iterating with each person´s name:
4. For each person´s name which exists in the gantt chart to be summarized, start creating new rows per each day they have activities scheduled (I can´t figure out yet how I´d iterate through this).
5. Within the each person´s loop, start iterating each row on the original sheet, evaluating each start and end date´s and pasting on the new sheet´s current person´s current day row a "1" if the condition was true in the corresponding hours.
6. Loop until all individual activities of each person are finished.
7. Continue with next person.

I´d like to know if this is the logical way to go and if you have any pointers or similar code to recycle, I am not proficient in VBA and Excel macros.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly.  So, you are using your formula in each of the cells after the "Finish" time (i called it "chart cells") and format those that are with value 1, right?  If so, just using a `=sumif([name range], "[each name]", [for each column of the chart cells])`, then, just doing the same conditional formatting with value >0. Then, it is a summary chart. Depends on your usage, you can have different ways to extract the unique names in the name range.

Comment: @OliverLeung that´s totally correct. And that SUMIF would definitely solve the problem of summarizing everything for each name. How could I extract it by day and add the other people autonomously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to extract unique records per person and day to get a person/day summary of time availability **but also** want it to be automated as you add more people and days.

I was able to do this with a combination of powerquery and a pivot table. When new persons/dates are added or changed the report will update but you will need to refresh using CTRL+ALT+F5

1. you want to highlight your entire report or an area as big as you think it will get. While highlighted you will then utilize named range feature under FORMULAS tab -> DEFINED NAMES ribbon -> DEFINED NAME dropdown. We could name it REPORTAREA or something like that.

**Make sure you change the conditional format formula in report to show 0 instead of "" so this can work properly**

2 go to DATA tab -> GET AND TRANSFORM ribbon -> From other sources -> Blank Query.
This will open the power query editor as a blank query

3 In the formula bar type =Excel.CurrentWorkbook() case sensitive is important

4 From there you will see CONTENT and NAME column.
In the NAME Column select the drop down and go to TEXT FILTERS -> Equals... Type in the name of your named range so the query does not pick up anything else on accident.

5 Remove the NAME column by right click selecting it and then remove.

6 you will notice the CONTENT column has two curved arrows pointing left and right instead of straight down like you are used to in excel. Click these arrows and make sure you uncheck the "use original column name as prefix" option box and ensure that the EXPAND option is selected. Then click okay.

7 At this point it looks alot like your report. Go to the HOME tab -> TRANSFORM ribbon -> Use first row as headers.

8.Select only the columns that are NOT THE 24 hr STYLE TIME LABELS of your report and then right click -> Unpivot other columns

9 At this point you can start removing some of the columns you dont want by right click and remove. Also double click and rename the columns as you wish. You can right click the top of the column and change types to what you want.
Dont worry about the 24HR style time zones not looking correct as this will be fixed later, this column should be changed to decimal type and not time zone type.

10. select a column that has the date information you need and right click -> Duplicate column -> change type to date.

11.At the top left part of the screen there is a CLOSE AND LOAD drop down where you will load to a new worksheet.

12. That will produce a green table. Select the table and press ALT+D+P to produce a pivot table linked to the green table you produced from the query.
13. You may need to close the Queries and Connections box that opened in order to see the pivot table options that will appear on you right.
    Drag the 24hr style column to the columns area.
    Drag the People to the Rows area and after Drag the Column you made in step 10 to the Rows area.
    Drag the conditional format column to the Values area.
14. Your pivot table wont look exactly like what you want. while pivot table is selected go to DESIGN tab -> REPORT LAYOUT -> Tabular and also SUBTOTALS -> DO NOT SHOW SUBTOTALS while in the same tab.

13 Highlight all of the 24hr style time labels and format them and after highlight the inside of the pivot table where all the 1 and 0 will be and apply the conditional formatting you applied previously. Dont forget you changed the formula originally so your if statement does not end with "" but instead with 0.

If you would like i think it is easier to switch around the ROWS and COLUMNS area of the pivot table fields so that the report is easier to read. I have chosen to do so in the pictures. If you want to keep the report the way you are used to you can follow previous instructions.
[image]

Comment: @Roy Is what i suggested sounding like the solution you were looking for?

Comment: This is a very good automated option for what I´m looking for. I followed through until the making of the Pivot Table. I don´t understand how you got the "Time Header" Column?. At the beggining I selected the whole report, including all the individual 24 HOUR time labels from 07:00 to 20:00; is this what you meant in step 8?

Comment: And how did you get the whole Time Header? I think that´s the only thing I´m Missing

Comment: At the beginning of the process you were supposed to highlight the whole report for the named range that is correct. the time header column is actually your 24hour time labels. I just renamed the column after unpivot to time header but you can use whatever name you like. The purpose of step 8 (unpivot other columns) is to make the time labels vertical instead of horizontal and change the report structure slightly at the same time for easier pivot table use. Does the green table look similar to mine or is it only the pivot table giving you trouble?

Comment: I think i understand. in my picture time header column shows first row as .291666667 see? That is actually 7:00 but excel shows only formatting. In really excel thinks .291666667. I pasted your 24hour time labels but power query stripped away the formatting. Later i reapplied the formatting to the pivot table so you can see it as you wish.

Comment: OK I almost got it, I just can´t get the 24 hour time labels formated correctly, I already tried to change the format to time but it doesnt change, any ideas? I attached the picture in the original question. Also, how do I get rid of the total counts adding up on the right of every person?

Comment: The total counts adding up is i believe part of step 14. You want to select the pivot table and then select the design tab to remove grand totals and subtotals. Should solve that problem.

Comment: OK I got it Working! I'm just still having trouble with the time format, I added another column and divided every value by one and formatted to time and this works, I just don´t know why the other format won´t work.

Comment: The total counts adding up is i believe part of step 14. You want to select the pivot table and then select the design tab to remove grand totals and subtotals. Should solve that problem. I tried to search for .125 but somehow it does not show up on my workbook and does show on yours. I think the original data may have been adjusted incorrectly or you may need to select the green table -> right click -> refresh? .125 is not a time value in your original report. and neither is zero. Smallest value should be 0.291666666666667

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216903/discussion-between-moises-mera-and-roy).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand properly, but it looks like you got a set of multiple records where you store the times In and Out of each worker, several rows for each worker.

And based on that, you would like to resume data, one row per worker, highlighting start and end time of each worker, but all in a single row.

I made a fake dataset like this:

[image]

I added 2 extra columns (you can even hide them if you don't want to see them)

1. Field `START TIME` got this formula:`=B2-INT(B2)`
2. Field `END TIME` got this formula: `=C2-INT(C2)`

In Excel, Dates are integers values and times are decimal values. I used both formulas to get only the decimal part of each start and end.

All this data is a table object named `T_WORKERTIMES`. I made a table object so if you add new records, the Gant Chart will autoupdate.

Then I made a simple (kind of horrible) Gant Chart:

[image]

The formula I've used in H2 and drag is:
`=COUNTIFS(T_WORKERTIMES[Worker];$G2;T_WORKERTIMES[start time];"<="&H$1;T_WORKERTIMES[end time];">="&H$1)`

Actually, all my data is in same sheet:

[image]

I added 2 Conditional Formating Rules to highlight cells in green/white if the result of the formula is 1/0.

Also, working with times sometimes can be hard, because decimals. `0,677083333335759` means `16:15`. But `0,6770833333333333` too, so in Gant Chart I rounded up headers to 6 decimals.

My formula in H1 is `=ROUND(7/24;6)`
My formula in J1 and drag to right is `=ROUND(H1+1/24/4;6)`

So now everything works fine. Please, notice in worker 1, there is no activites from 07:00 to 08:00. So I add a new row with that data and everything updates:

[image]

I've uploaded a sample yo Google Drive you can see the formulas and hope you can adapt this to your needs.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KOuCAYsmlY9gfNUCUhIrihXu-tJz-K7t/view?usp=sharing

Biggest issue here is the decimal part of times, to make sure they fit the Gant Chart. An easy solution would be substracting just 1 minute to start time column (calculated, you can hide it) and sum 1 minute to end time column (calculated, you can hide it).

Hope this can guide you in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I put the above comment down here as a complete answer.

I call those cells after "Finish date" column as "Chart cells". To extract a unique list of names, please refers to: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252602/excel-formula-of-extract-unique-items-from-list-with-condition)

If each name, you can use the followings formula and format for cells value >0 to show the bars.

```
=SUMIF([name range], "[each name]", [for each column of the chart cells])
```

If you further needs to filter by dates, you need to use `sumifs()` instead:

```
=SUMIFS([each column of chart cells], [name range], [unique name obtained from above], [Finish date range],"<=" & DATEVALUE("[target date]")+1,[start date range],"<=" & DATEVALUE("[target date]"))
```

This is the Excel formula solution, which is good if your table is not huge.

Comment: I don´t understand what I should put in target date, can you ellaborate please?

Comment: My bad. I fixed the formula. Just enter the text string of the date you want the summary to be. e.g. If you want the summary of 24/Jun/2020, replace the placeholder `[target date]` with "24/Jun/2020"