# Trying to create a dynamic gant chart in excel using conditional formatting when reference against an activities dates and times

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I'm trying to get one of my excel sheets to produce a gantt chart to aid in the user in understanding when activities take place, and their connection with each other.
So far i've managed to get the time section to work but now i want the cells to conditionally format if the within the start and end date. I'm using the below formula.

=AND(F$7>=$D8,F$7<=$E8)

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot showing `$D8` in empty.

Comment: Hi Harus24HR I didnt think that would matter as its just the top of the column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate summary gantt chart from detailed activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546036/generate-summary-gantt-chart-from-detailed-activities)